# Realizando update em vários registros para o mesmo ID

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Considere o seguinte cenário para o controle de informações sobre as licenças em um banco de dados

**Produtos**

```
1 - Solução x 
2 - Solução y
3 - Solução z
```

Suponha que o Cliente tenha as 3 soluções

**Tabela Licenças**

```
| ID | CLIENTE_ID | PRODUTO_ID | DATA_VALIDADE_INICIAL | DATA_VALIDADE_FINAL |
| 1  | 11222      |     1      |    2015-01-01         |   2016-01-01        |
| 2  | 11222      |     2      |    2015-01-01         |   2016-01-01        |
| 3  | 11222      |     3      |    2015-01-01         |   2016-01-01        |
```

Meu objetivo e realizar atualização do prazo de licença de todos os produtos para um cliente especifico.

Inicialmente utilizei a seguinte instrução para realizar update de todas as licenças do cliente , veja :

```
UPDATE licenca
SET 
data_validade_inicial= '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
data_validade_final= '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
WHERE cliente_id = 11222
```

Gostaria de aprimorar esta funcionalidade por exemplo caso o cliente deseje atualizar somente duas licenças em uma unica ação como posso implementar isso ?

Comment: Por "atualizar somente 2" devemos entender o produto 2 ?

Comment: atualizei a pergunta me desculpe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parceiro, você precisará de um checkbox ao lado de cada registro na sua listagem, para marcar os registros que deseja alterar.

A sua instrução SQL ficará assim:

```
UPDATE licenca
SET data_validade_inicial= '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
    data_validade_final= '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
WHERE cliente_id = 11222 AND produto_id IN (1,3)
```

Nesse exemplo, será atualizado a validade dos produtos com id = 1 e id =3 do cliente = 11222.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: kk esses ferias me deixaram enferrujado pra caramba =x Muito obrigado !

Comment: @stringnome vlw

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE licenca
SET data_validade_inicial= '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
    data_validade_final= '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
WHERE cliente_id = 11222
    AND produto_id in (1,3)
```

ou se quiser pelo nome do produto:

```
UPDATE lic
SET lic.data_validade_inicial= '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
    lic.data_validade_final= '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
FROM licenca lic
    INNER JOIN produto pr on lic.produto_id = pr.id
WHERE lic.cliente_id = 11222
    AND pr.nome in ('Solução x', 'Solução z')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção @nuno